# How do I generate a key pair with Web Crypto and access its keys in a Firefox AddOn?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, webcrypto-api

I'd like to call `window.crypto.subtle.generateKey` in my Firefox AddOn. Since I can not access `window` in *main.js* I create a [page-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker#Page) with a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker#contentScriptFile):

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
var cryptoScript = require('sdk/page-worker').Page({
  contentURL: self.data.url('empty.html'),
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url('call-web-crypto.js')
});
```

I can call `window.crypto.subtle.generateKey` in *call-web-crypto.js*, but I can not access the key properties of the generated key pair:

XrayWrapper denied access to property publicKey (reason: value not same-origin with target). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Xray_vision for more information. Note that only the first denied property access from a given global object will be reported.

How can I generate a key pair and access its keys in my Firefox Addon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in *main.js* you can ...

```
const { Cu } = require("chrome");
Cu.importGlobalProperties(["crypto"]);
```

then you'll have access to `crypto.subtle.generateKey` as well as all the other `crypto` goodness ... note no `window`

Comment: Also works fine in all add-on scripts `require`d from *main.js* (or *index.js*, the modern name).

Comment: @user - `main.js` `index.js` are just names - it can be `fred.js` - I specified `main.js` as that is what the original question specified :p

Comment: I just wondered when I read the question. Thus, maybe someone else did, too, and this little tidbit helps them.