# window.crypto equivalent in addon

Tags: javascript, cryptography, firefox-addon

Is there a clean way to access secure cryptography in an addon script?

Injecting a page-mod which `port.emit()`s the result of `window.crypto.getRandomValues()` should be possible, but seems untidy.

The [AddonSDKCryptoAPI](https://wiki.mozilla.org/AddonSDKCryptoAPI) offers only high-level primitives, and the draft has not been updated for 4 years.

Comment: maybe my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562588/how-do-i-generate-a-key-pair-with-web-crypto-and-access-its-keys-in-a-firefox-ad/33564865#33564865) will help

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes, it worked perfectly. Thanks.